# como eu poderia usar no lugar de passar um id, passar uma Class no JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho esse código aqui:
HTML: `<button class="btn btn-danger btn-circle delete" type="button"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></b</td>`

```
$('#submit1, #submit2').click(function () {
   if (this.id == 'submit1') {
      alert('Submit 1 clicked');
   }
   else if (this.id == 'submit2') {
      alert('Submit 2 clicked');
   }
});
```

Eu gostaria de passar uma *class* no lugar de um *id*, como faço? Devo usar um `this.class` no lugar do `this.id`? e passar :

```
$('.submit1, .submit2').click(function () {
       if (this.class == 'submit1') {
          alert('Submit 1 clicked');
       }
});
```

Comment: Inclusa seu html à pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem a pergunta você procura algo assim.

```js
$('.btnSubmit').click(function () {      
    var button = $(this);
    //console.log("Você clicou em: " + $(this).attr('id'));
    if($(button).hasClass('sim'))
    {
      swal({
        title: 'Obrigado por escolher SIM!',
        html: '<strong>Informe seu e-mail:</strong>',
        input: 'text',
        preConfirm: (value) => {
          if (!value) {
            swal.showValidationError('Não pode ser vazio!')
          }
        }
      }).then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
      });
    }
    else
    {
      swal({
        title: 'Você escolheu não!',
        html: '<strong>Obrigado mesmo assim</strong>'        
      }); 
    }
});
```

```css
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.3.5/sweetalert2.min.css";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.3.5/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<button id="Submit1" class="btnSubmit sim">Sim</button>
<button id="Submit2" class="btnSubmit">Não</button>
```

Comment: sim é mais ou menos isso. clicar em um botão para me trazer um alert usando um "sweet Alert"

Comment: Alterei a resposta utilizando o sweet alert e validando as condições.

Comment: Valeu @Leandro Angelo.

Answer (score 1):

O código que tem para os eventos de click é um pouco estranho e deveria ser:

```
$('#submit1').click(function () {
   alert('Submit 1 clicked');
});

$('#submit2').click(function () {
   alert('Submit 2 clicked');
});
```

Se precisa de chegar ao elemento através da classe a unica coisa que precisa de alterar é mesmo o seletor, passando de `#` para `.`

```
$('.submit1').click(function () {
   alert('Submit 1 clicked');
});

$('.submit2').click(function () {
   alert('Submit 2 clicked');
});
```

Isto irá implicar que tenha a classe atribuída no elemento correto no html.

**Edit:**

Se quisesse manter o estilo que tinha (que eu não conselho) poderia faze-lo baseando-se em [`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/):

```js
$('.submit1, .submit2').click(function () {
     if ($(this).hasClass('submit1')) {
        alert('Submit 1 clicked');
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" class="submit1" value="Submit 1">
<input type="submit" class="submit2" value="Submit 2">
```

Comment: Dessa forma fiz ja e funcionou mas queria saber daquele jeito que especifiquei, se havia um jeito de fazer.Mas a sua resposta é boa.

Comment: @Gladiador Do jeito que tinha era preciso utilizar `$(this)` para ir buscar o objeto JQuery e teria que consultar se tem a classe como método [`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/), mas acaba por estar a reinventar a roda uma vez que os seletores servem precisamente para conseguir chegar aos elementos que pretende.

Comment: Entendi. valeu pela dica @Isac

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar desta manteira:

```
$('.submit1, .submit2').click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('class').indexOf('submit1') >= 0) {
        alert('Submit 1 clicked');
    }
    else if ($(this).attr('class').indexOf('submit2') >= 0) {
        alert('Submit 2 clicked');
    }
}
```

Comment: não deu certo @rLinhares